# How to get pivot data specific to user in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `users` table, an `items` table and a pivot table `item_user`.

I can get a list of all users items or a list of all an items users easy enough using `belongsToMany` relationship.

```
$item->users;
$user->items;
```

However I'm using this as a sort of "favorites" relationship.

So if I display ALL items on my website regardless of user, I want to know which ones the user has in the pivot table as the "favorite".

So far I have this:

```
// Item Model

public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('user_id')->where('user_id', @\Auth::user()->id);
}
```

It works fine, but the query it runs is this:

```
select `users`.*, `item_user`.`item_id` as `pivot_item_id`, `item_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `item_user` on `users`.`id` = `item_user`.`user_id` where `user_id` = '1' and `item_user`.`item_id` in ('282', '10', '826', '632', '896', '604', '8', '990', '175', '979', '7', '805', '665', '263', '507', '327', '397', '208', '762', '926', '474', '389', '433', '742', '613', '689', '782', '435', '898', '518')
```

I don't need the data from the `users` table, I just need the pivot data:

```
SELECT user_id, item_id FROM item_user WHERE user_id = 1 AND item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 282);
```

Is there anyway to run the more efficient version in Laravel?

Comment: Basically as I understand your requirement, if user contain any item than it would be `favourite` , So definably you need to get pivot by user or item. because pivot contain user_id and item_id... if you have anyone... you can easily get pivot data by calling  
`$user = User::find();` than `$user->pivot->item_id`....

Comment: or `$item = Item::find(1);` then `$item->pivot->user_id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As much I understand your requirement.. it can be resolve by adding a column to pivot table.

First include 'favorite' on your pivot call to Item Model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_items')
             ->withPivot('favorite');
```

Note: Vice versa can also define but didn't test that option.

Then to check weather it 'favorite' or not :

```
$item = User::with('items')->get()->find(1)->items->find(2)->pivot->favorite;
```

But in that case you also need to organise you relationship structure as user has many items. If you still any question to understand my approach please let me know.